# As an indie developer, what should I learn about the business end of game development?

Tags: business

I assume I should look into intellectual property law, copyright law, and money management, but what else would be good to know? My ideal goal is to be able to handle all legal/monetary business internally, without hiring an outside lawyer.

Comment: Good question and welcome to the site.

Comment: Are you alone or do you have a partneship? If you are alone, you could go by without a lawyer but if you have other people, my recommendation from personal experience is to talk to lawyers who specialize in start ups (and they are relatively cheap). There are so many things to take care of that only a lawyer can inform/warn you about.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also starting an indie development company. I'm not very experienced in this matter, but here is what I'm going to do:

Have a low-risk pay model (no-one gets paid a cent until the company has recouped the initiation costs of the project, after that people get paid a percentage of money from that project depending on how much work they did, the company gets a percentage too)

Learn about bankruptcy - If you're in a business structure with Unlimited Liability it is important that you understand the risks you are taking. If the risk is too big you may wish to fork out extra to get a Limited Liability business.

Don't copy other people's stuff unless it is free domain or you have written permission. Even then be careful.

If you ever need to take someone else to court because they copied your stuff, hire a lawyer. Seriously.

It's not much info, but I hope it helps.